# PySpark dynamic column computation

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark

Below is my spark data frame

```
a b c
1 3 4
2 0 0
4 1 0
2 2 0
```

My output should be as below

```
a b c
1 3 4
2 0 2
4 1 -1
2 2 3
```

Formula is `prev(c)-b+a` i.e, `4-2+0=2` and `2-4+1=-1`

Comment: It is assumed that you already tried to do something to solve this. Tell us what you tried to do please.

Comment: So, what's your problem? You've got precise formula, you can easily search how to get previous value and how to sum fields

Comment: Yes I used below approach ,

approach was created new column c_new which lags by 1 and did c_new-a+b later analyzed the values has to be dynamically taken from previously generated values of c_new.

 Below is the code

df = df.withColumn('c_new',func.lag(df['c']).over(Window.partitionBy("a").orderBy("a")))

df = df.withColumn('Stock_New',(df['c_new'] - stock_output_table['a']) + stock_output_table['b'] )

I got stuck up here not knowing how to dynamically take the values from c_new

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lag, udf
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

numbers = [[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5],[5,6,7]]
df = sc.parallelize(numbers).toDF(['a','b','c'])
df.show()

w = Window().partitionBy().orderBy('a')
calculate = udf(lambda a,b,c:a-b+c,IntegerType())
df = df.withColumn('result', lag("a").over(w)-df.b+df.c)
df.show()



+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|
+---+---+---+
|  1|  2|  3|
|  2|  3|  4|
|  3|  4|  5|
|  5|  6|  7|
+---+---+---+

+---+---+---+------+
|  a|  b|  c|result|
+---+---+---+------+
|  1|  2|  3|  null|
|  2|  3|  4|     2|
|  3|  4|  5|     3|
|  5|  6|  7|     4|
+---+---+---+------+
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer. But this is not working if my dataframe is like this numbers = [[1,1,2,3],[1,1,2,3],[2,2,3,4],[3,3,4,5],[3,3,4,5],[3,3,4,5],[4,5,6,7]]
df = sc.parallelize(numbers).toDF(['cat','a','b','c'])
w = Window().partitionBy().orderBy('cat')
df = df.withColumn('result', lag("a").over(w)-df.b+df.c). Should I take any distinct at the end please help

Comment: It works just fine fore me... given your dataset above

Comment: Can you please help me the dataset given above

Comment: Yes it works just fine for me... given your formula prev(a)-b+c. Can you tell me what error do you get.

Comment: I am not getting any error If I use this dataset numbers = [[1,1,2,3],[1,1,2,3],[2,2,3,4],[3,3,4,5],[3,3,4,5],[3,3,4,5]‌​,[4,5,6,7]] . Output is not getting replicated properly for third row of 3 4 5 output should be as 3 3 4 5 5 . but getting as 3 3 4 5 4 . Formula not getting replicated properly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154817/discussion-between-naveen-srikanth-and-stackpointer).

Answer (score 1):

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

df = sc.parallelize([
    [1,3],
    [2,0],
    [4,1],
    [2,2]
]).toDF(('a', 'b'))

df1 = df.withColumn("row_id", f.monotonically_increasing_id())
w = Window.partitionBy().orderBy(f.col("row_id"))
df1 = df1.withColumn("c_temp", f.when(f.col("row_id")==0, f.lit(4)).otherwise(- f.col("a") + f.col("b")))
df1 = df1.withColumn("c", f.sum(f.col("c_temp")).over(w)).drop("c_temp","row_id")
df1.show()
```

Output is:

```
+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|
+---+---+---+
|  1|  3|  4|
|  2|  0|  2|
|  4|  1| -1|
|  2|  2| -1|
+---+---+---+
```