# Pyspark column generation on lookup of previous rows and compute

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark

Need to generate the column dynamically with look up on previous row values.

So far tried on Code which is shared below

Spark Dataframe is below

```
cat a    b    c
1   null 0    0
1   0    9    0 
2   0    126  0
2   7    0    0
2   36   0    0
3   35   0    0
```

Output should be as below

```
cat a    b    c    d
1   null 0    0    null
1   0    9    0    0
2   0    126  0    9
2   7    0    0    119
2   36   0    0    83 
2   35   0    0    48
```

Here column `d` is dynamically generated below is the code used and not working

```
w=Window().partitionBy().orderBy('cat')
df=df.withColumn('d',lag("b").over(w)-df.a+df.c)
df.show()
```

Problem is formula is not getting replicated prperly formula is prev(b)-a+c

Comment: can you explain the logic of your expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

df = sc.parallelize([
    [1,None, 0, 0],
    [1,0,9,0],
    [2,0,126,0],
    [2,7,0,0],
    [2,36,0,0],
    [2,35,0,0]
]).toDF(('cat','a', 'b', 'c'))

df1 = df.withColumn("row_id", f.monotonically_increasing_id())
w = Window.partitionBy().orderBy(f.col("row_id"))
df1 = df1.withColumn("d", f.lag("b").over(w)- f.col("a") + f.col("c")).drop("row_id")
df1.show()
```

Output is:

```
+---+----+---+---+----+
|cat|   a|  b|  c|   d|
+---+----+---+---+----+
|  1|null|  0|  0|null|
|  1|   0|  9|  0|   0|
|  2|   0|126|  0|   9|
|  2|   7|  0|  0| 119|
|  2|  36|  0|  0| -36|
|  2|  35|  0|  0| -35|
+---+----+---+---+----+
```

Comment: I have this logic Prem but output has to be 2 36 0 0 83 not -36

Comment: With the calculation you have mentioned in your post, how can it be 83? Pls explain

Comment: Thanks for quick response Prem. When column d is being populated it has to take previous row value I should be getting as 119-36+0=83 then for next row I should be getting as 83-35+0=48 that is 2 35 0 0 48. I understand as I am mentioning lag(b) since other lag values are 0 it is getting as -36 but ideally when populating the column d which is lagging from column b it has to dynamically take previous values from column d .

Comment: Your requirement is completely confusing so suggest you to kindly update your question properly. BTW few hours back I think [exactly similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46304475/pyspark-dynamic-column-computation) has been posted by other user. [My solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46304475/pyspark-dynamic-column-computation/46307804#46307804) over there might interest you.

Comment: One more thing is this has to be done partition over by cat because for last row 3 35 0 0 value should be null it handles by lag . Trying this logic for days please help